# Blazor Server and the Entity Framework. How to avoid multiple conflicting calls to the DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

**Summary**

In my Razor page, a single user action fires off two events.  These events result in calls to the EF which result in the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=A
>   second operation started on this context before a previous operation
>   completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same
>   instance of DbContext.

**Setup**
Rather than have one huge DBContext, I have multiple contexts, each focused on a small area of functionality in the DB.  So, let's imagine that here I'm dealing with functionality for working with People.

I therefore have a PeopleContext, and a PeopleService.  In my startup, these are registered as:

```
services.AddDbContext<PeopleContext>();
services.AddScoped<PeopleService>();
```

And the Context is Dependency Injected into the Service:

```
public class PeopleService
{
    public PeopleService(PeopleContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context;
    }

    private PeopleContext Context { get; }
```

**Actions**

So picture a page that has a grid on the left hand side showing a summary of each person, and an area on the right hand side where we show the details of the selected person.

When someone clicks a row of a grid, we make a call to the Service to load the full details of that person and display that data in the right hand side.

We also have an [Edit] button on the grid.  When someone clicks that, it opens up a modal window.  That window makes a call the the SAME method on the SAME Service (therefore using the SAME Context) to load the full details so that we can edit the person.

So, my problem is of course that when someone clicks the [Edit] button in the Grid, they're also selecting the current row and so that method gets called twice at almost the same time, resulting in the above conflict.

**Solution**

I don't think that I want to intoduce the concept of locking because that can lead to performance issues.  I also don't want to duplicate the method in a different Service because I want to keep my code DRY.  I'm not sure it makes great sense to not fire the SELECT ROW event when someone clicks the button on the row.  I also can't be the first person to come across this, so there must be an established "best practice" for this sort of behaviour - hence this post to hopefully discover what that is.

---

Using: Blazor Server, .NET 3.1

Comment: In .NET Core 3.1, I understand that we'll have the ability to call "prevent default" which will stop events from bubbling up through the DOM.  However, not sure that's the solution since we may want these to all fire.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue in my Blazor Server project (.NET 5.0), with Entity Framework Core, where a call to the service to load entities is made in each component's `OnInitializedAsync()` method. The ApplicationDbContext is scoped, and if a user would navigate too quickly between components, that same service method would also get called simultaneously from the other component leading to the above error:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: A second operation was
> started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is
> usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same
> instance of DbContext.

**Fix:** At first I realised that changing my ApplicationDbContext's registration to Transient fixed the issue - however I do not want to lose the Unit of Work and Change Tracking funcionality. Instead I now keep the ApplicationDbContext as Scoped, and fix the issue as follows:

**In MainLayout component:** I create a named [Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphore?view=net-5.0) object, to be used globally in all components:

```
 @code {
    static Semaphore semaphore;
    //code ommitted for brevity
    
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
     {
        if (!Semaphore.TryOpenExisting("GlobalSemaphore", out semaphore))
        {
           semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "GlobalSemaphore");
        }
     }
```

**In each component**, before any service calls where I need to prevent simultaneous calls to the database (in my case this happens in `OnInitializedAsync()`:

```
  @code {
        static Semaphore semaphore;
        //code ommitted for brevity
        
         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
             try
             {
                //First open global semaphore
                semaphore = Semaphore.OpenExisting("GlobalSemaphore");

                while (!semaphore.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1)))
                {
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
                //If while loop is exited or skipped, previous service calls are completed.
                ApplicationUsers = await ApplicationUserService.Get();        
             
             }
             finally
             {
                try
                {
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ex.Message");
                }
            }
        }
```

Therefore, while another component is still busy making calls to services, I can check each second until the semaphore is released - and then continue to make calls to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution was:

**Razor Page**

```
@inherits OwningComponentBase<Data.MyService>
```

**Startup**

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
services.AddScoped<MyService>();
```

For more details, see: [Using Entity Framework Core with Blazor #10448](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10448)